# How is query performance affected by the number of records in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rails-activerecord

Is the query speed affected by the number of rows?

Let's say we have an active record model "Post", and many of those have a status=false, would it be useful, if all the records with status=false are not gonna be used, but are necessary, to create a different model, like "OffPost" to store all those posts with status false, so when I query any object in "Post" the query is faster? or just a scope getting all Post with a status equal to true, would represent the same efficiency?

Comment: Creating a new model has no efficiency, it's all a database query in the end. Database indexes are usually the first thing to look at to improve db performance. Creating a materialized view might be something for you to read up on, Postgres has good support for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you frequently query by status, the most important thing would be to add an index to the status column first.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

The speed is indeed affected by the number of rows and splitting tables or the whole database (e.g. by country, city, user ids) is one strategy to keep the number of records low. This is called shardening (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)). However, introducing this kind of logic comes with a big price of a more complex system which is more difficult to maintain and understand (e.g. queries will get more difficult). It is only worth if you have billions of records. If you only have a few (hundred) million records, selecting good indexes on the table is the best approach.

If the records with `status=false` are not used in your application but necessary e.g. for data analysis another approach could be to move them to a data warehouse from time to time and delete from your database to keep the number of rows small. But again, you introduce more complexity with a data warehouse.